# Issue with an intent working on Lollipop and older, but not on newer

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on an activity that will let the user select an image from the gallery, and then put that image's URI into an SQLite database.

I have another activity where I take that URI and display it on an ImageView. I have this working perfectly on Lollipop and older. But anything newer it crashes when I pull up the activity that displays the image.

Here is the LOGCAT line of the crash:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider.MediaContentProvider from ProcessRecord{8193e94 13574:jeremy.com.wineofmine/u0a97} (pid=13574, uid=10097) that is not exported from uid 10044
```

This makes it seem like a permissions thing, but I am requesting the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL STORAGE` in the manifest, as well as requesting those permissions on run-time on the activity where it displays the image.

And here is the exact line where it's crashing (this is in the activity where it displays the image:)

```
bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageURI);
```

And this is imageURI:

```
imageURI = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(WineContract.WineEntry.COLUMN_WINE_IMAGE)));
//This code returns this: content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F62/ACTUAL/860591124
```

---

Here is the code to the relevant bits.

This is the intent to open up the gallery:

```
Intent intentGallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intentGallery, SELECT_IMAGE);
```

And this is the `onActivityResult` method. The main goal of this method is to set the imageThumbail ImageView as the thumbnail, and also to set "photoURI" as the selected image's URI.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
//This is if they choose an image from the gallery
    if (requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if (requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE) {
            // Get the url from data
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            if (null != selectedImageUri) {
                // Get the path from the Uri
                String path = getPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
                Log.i("ADDACTIVITY", "Image Path : " + path);

                bitmap = null;
                try {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                bitmapThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmap,175,175);
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmapThumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

    // Set the image in ImageView
                imageThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bitmapThumbnail);
    //Setting photoURI (which gets put into the database) as the gallery's image URI
                photoURI = data.getData();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any pointers to what I could be doing wrong, would be great.

Comment: "I am currently working on an activity that will let the user select an image from the gallery, and then put that image's URI into an SQLite database" -- that will not work in general by default. If the `Uri` has a `content` scheme, by default, you have limited time to use that content before your access rights lapse. Since you are using `ACTION_PICK`, you have no means of getting durable access rights for the `Uri`.

Comment: `But anything newer it crashes`. If you catch that SecurityException your app will not crash.

Comment: @CommonsWare So basically the URI would sort of "expire" after a while? Would be there a better option than ACTION_PICK to use? I've also tried things like ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT and ACTION_GET_CONTENT but those also gave me a lot of trouble.

Comment: "basically the URI would sort of "expire" after a while?" -- [yes](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html). "Would be there a better option than ACTION_PICK to use?" -- `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` gives you the option of perhaps using `takePersistableUriPermission()` to get long-term access to the content (assuming that the user does not delete or move it). Otherwise, import the photos into your app.

Comment: @CommonsWare I had the best luck with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, but the problem I had is that I couldn't select from the full gallery. It wasn't an option. I could only select from "recents" and "downloads." The full gallery wasn't even an option for me.

Comment: Well, there is no "gallery" with `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`. The user can choose to view "internal storage" (really the SDK's external storage) via an overflow menu item.

Comment: @CommonsWare I just tried OPEN_DOCUMENT again and on my own phone for testing, I can enable Internal Storage in the drop down menu, but in the DCIM folder I just don't see any of my images I've taken.

Comment: Perhaps they are located elsewhere. Or, perhaps your MIME type for the `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` `Intent` isn't for images.

Comment: @CommonsWare This is what the intent looks lke: https://pastebin.com/329mTev6

Comment: That should be OK; I cannot explain why you cannot see your photos.